# Programming with C# console application

Tags: c#

```
Convert.ToString((input.Split(' ').Length + 1), 2).PadLeft(8, '0')
```

could anybody explain this line for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a tutorial site. You can find full documentation for C# at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes an input string (`input`), splits it on the space character (`input.Split(' ')`) (presumably to get the number of "words"), adds 1 to the `.Length` of the resulting array (not sure why), converts that number to a binary string (`Convert.ToString(int, 2)` will convert the int to a base-2 number and return it as a string), then pads the left side of the string with the `0` character until it's `8` characters long (`.PadLeft(8, '0')`).

My guess is that this might be used in some kind of encoding/decoding algorithm(?).

Here it is in action:

```
var inputStrings = new List<string>
{
    "one",
    "two words",
    "this is three",
    "this one is four",
    "and this one has five"
};

foreach(var input in inputStrings)
{
    var result = Convert.ToString((input.Split(' ').Length + 1), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');

    Console.WriteLine($"{input.PadRight(22, ' ')} = {result}");
}

Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split it up:

```
var stringItems = input.Split(' ');
```

Split the input string on spaces

---

```
int itemCount = stringItems.Length + 1;
```

However many items are in the collection, add one to that

---

```
var str = Convert.ToString(itemCount, 2);
```

Call some overload of Convert.ToString that takes two ints as parameters (I have no idea what this is). [Consult Documentation as we have no idea what this overload does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

It turns out that it:

> Converts the value of a 32-bit signed integer to its equivalent string representation in a specified base

So we have a string from a 32 bit integer in base 2.

---

```
str.PadLeft(8, '0')
```

Make sure the string has 8 characters total, all 0's except the one's that existed already.

---

Looks like we created a pretty binary number.  Though I have no idea what the meaning of it is without context.